# GLTF index count same as buffer size error

Tags: javascript, webgl, gltf

I am working on learning WebGL and having a great time! I decided to use glTF as the 3d format for this project. I have it working well, with one weird exception. When the index count is low (say a simple triangulated cube), the index count equals the index buffer size. This can't be right. In every other model I have, the index count is 1/2 the size of the buffer.

These causes render errors like this "Error: WebGL warning: drawElements: Index buffer too small.". Below is the relevant code.

Renderable Constructor:

```
constructor(type,indexCount,vertBuffer,indexBuffer,uvBuffer,normalBuffer,modelMatrix){
    this.type = type;
    this.indexCount = indexCount;

    this.name = "NONE";

    this.vertBuffer = GL.createBuffer();
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertBuffer);
    GL.bufferData(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer, GL.STATIC_DRAW);
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

    this.uvBuffer = GL.createBuffer();
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.uvBuffer);
    GL.bufferData(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer, GL.STATIC_DRAW);
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

    this.indexBuffer = GL.createBuffer();
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexBuffer);
    GL.bufferData(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer, GL.STATIC_DRAW);
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

    this.normalBuffer = GL.createBuffer();
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalBuffer);
    GL.bufferData(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer, GL.STATIC_DRAW);
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

    this.matrix = modelMatrix;
    this.witMatrix = mat4.create();

    this.textures = [];

    //Create defaults
    this.setTexture(new dTexture(TEX.COLOR,"res/missingno.png"));
    this.setTexture(new dTexture(TEX.LIGHT,"res/rawLight.png"));
}
```

GLTF to "Renderable"

```
static fromGLTF(type,gltf){
    console.log("GLTF: loading "+gltf.nodes[0].name);
    return new Renderable(type,
        gltf.nodes[0].mesh.primitives[0].indicesLength,
        gltf.nodes[0].mesh.primitives[0].attributes.POSITION.bufferView.data,
        gltf.accessors[gltf.nodes[0].mesh.primitives[0].indices].bufferView.data,
        gltf.nodes[0].mesh.primitives[0].attributes.TEXCOORD_0.bufferView.data,
        gltf.nodes[0].mesh.primitives[0].attributes.NORMAL.bufferView.data,
        gltf.nodes[0].matrix);
}
```

Here is the rendering code (It's not very pretty, but for completeness, here it is):

```
render(){
    GL.viewport(0.0,0.0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
    GL.clear(GL.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    this.renderables.forEach(renderable => {

        //mat4.identity(renderable.witMatrix);
        mat4.invert(renderable.witMatrix,renderable.matrix);
        mat4.transpose(renderable.witMatrix,renderable.witMatrix);

        GL.useProgram(this.programs[renderable.type].program);
        GL.uniformMatrix4fv(this.programs[renderable.type].pMatrix, false, this.projectionMatrix);
        GL.uniformMatrix4fv(this.programs[renderable.type].vMatrix, false, this.viewMatrix);
        GL.uniformMatrix4fv(this.programs[renderable.type].mMatrix, false, renderable.matrix);

        GL.enableVertexAttribArray(this.programs[renderable.type].positon);
        GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER,renderable.vertBuffer);
        GL.vertexAttribPointer(this.programs[renderable.type].positon, 3, GL.FLOAT, false,0,0);

        GL.enableVertexAttribArray(this.programs[renderable.type].uv);
        GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER,renderable.uvBuffer);
        GL.vertexAttribPointer(this.programs[renderable.type].uv, 2, GL.FLOAT, false,0,0);

        if(renderable.type == SHADER.STATIC){
            GL.uniform1i(this.programs[renderable.type].colorPos, 0);  // texture unit 0
            GL.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE0);
            GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, renderable.textures[TEX.COLOR].data);

            GL.uniform1i(this.programs[renderable.type].lightPos, 1);  // texture unit 1
            GL.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE1);
            GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, renderable.textures[TEX.LIGHT].data);
        }else if(renderable.type == SHADER.DYNAMIC){
            GL.uniform1i(this.programs[renderable.type].colorPos, 0);  // texture unit 0
            GL.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE0);
            GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, renderable.textures[TEX.COLOR].data);

            GL.enableVertexAttribArray(this.programs[renderable.type].normalPos);
            GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER,renderable.normalBuffer);
            GL.vertexAttribPointer(this.programs[renderable.type].normalPos, 3, GL.FLOAT, false,0,0);

            GL.uniformMatrix4fv(this.programs[renderable.type].witMatrix, false, renderable.witMatrix);

            // set the light position
            GL.uniform3fv(this.programs[renderable.type].lightPosPos, [
                Math.sin(this.counter)*0.75,
                Math.cos(this.counter)*0.75+1,
                0
            ]);
            this.counter+=this.dt*0.25;
        }

        GL.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, renderable.indexBuffer);
        GL.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES,renderable.indexCount,GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

        GL.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE1);
        GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D,this.nullLightmap.data);
    });

    GL.flush();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *"When the index count is low (say a simple triangulated cube), the index count equals the index buffer size. This can't be right. In every other model I have, the index count is 1/2 the size of the buffer.*" I suppose that the type of the index buffer is `GL.UNSIGNED_BYTE`, when the number of indices is low, while the type of the index buffer is `GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT` or even `GL.UNSIGNED_INT`, if there are more indices. It the type is `GL.UNSIGNED_BYTE` the of course the number of indices is equal the size of the buffer in bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When the index count is low (say a simple triangulated cube), the index count equals the index buffer size. This can't be right. In every other model I have, the index count is 1/2 the size of the buffer.

The size of the index buffer depends on the number of indices and the `componentType`.
See [Accessor Element Size](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/specification/2.0#accessor-element-size):

> ```
> componentType         Size in bytes
> 5120 (BYTE)           1
> 5121 (UNSIGNED_BYTE)  1
> 5122 (SHORT)          2
> 5123 (UNSIGNED_SHORT) 2
> 5125 (UNSIGNED_INT)   4
> 5126 (FLOAT)          4
> ```

The `componentType` specifies the data type of a single index. When the number of indices is low (<= 256), then the data type `UNSIGNED_BYTE` is used, while the type of the index buffer is `UNSIGNED_SHORT` or even `UNSIGNED_INT`, if there are more indices. If the type is `UNSIGNED_BYTE`, then of course the number of indices is equal the size of the buffer in bytes.

Dependent on the type of the element indices you have to adept the draw call, e.g. `GL.UNSIGNED_BYTE`:

```
GL.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES,renderable.indexCount,GL.UNSIGNED_BYTE,0);
```

Note, the values of the `componentType` (5120, 5121, ...) which seems to be arbitrary, are the values of the OpenGL enumerator constants `GL.BYTE`, `GL.UNSIGNED_BYTE`, ...

I suggest to pass the `componentType` to the `constructor` as you do it with the number of indices (`indexCount`)

```
constructor(
    type,indexCount,componentType,
    vertBuffer,indexBuffer,uvBuffer,normalBuffer,modelMatrix){

    this.indexCount    = indexCount;
    this.componentType = componentType;
```

and to use it in when drawing the geometry:

```
GL.drawElements(
    GL.TRIANGLES,
    renderable.indexCount,
    renderable.componentType,
    0);
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks! Now that I see it, it makes all the sense in the world.